# Change font size of "Table of Contents" heading in memoir and make it bold

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, fontsize, bold

I'm using the `memoir` document class and the `babel` package and I need to change the size of the "Table of Contents" heading or at least to make it bold. Is it possible?

Comment: The title of `\tableofcontents` in memoir is formatted as chapter title, that means the font size is larger and **bold**.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek not necessarily; if one uses some of the predefined `chapterstyle`s the chapter titles won't, for example, be bold.

Answer (score 6):

The ToC, LoF and LoT titles use the same format as the chapter titles, and
will be typeset according to the current `chapterstyle`. This implies that the ToC, LoF, LoT titles might not be boldfaced and in a larger font for some `chapterstyle`s; for example, using the `dash` style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

one gets

[image]

You can modify the appearance of the ToC, LoT, LoF titles either by using a different `chapterstyle` for them, or by changing
`\printtoctitle`, `\printlottitle`, `\printloftitle`. A little example with the `dash` style and a redefinition of `\printtoctitle` to use `\huge` and boldfaced font for the ToC title would be:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\huge\bfseries #1}
\chapterstyle{dash}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to add few extra lines, this would also do:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\chapterstyle{dash}

\let\oldchaptitlefont\chaptitlefont
\def\contentstitlefont{\bfseries\Large}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\contentstitlefont}
\tableofcontents*
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\oldchaptitlefont}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}

\end{document}
```

Altough, not as clean as Gonzalo Medinas answer.